# How to make a grammar LL(1)?

Tags: compiler-construction, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar

I have this grammar that has to be transformed to LL(1) grammar:

```
S->A
A->BC|DBC
B->Bb|epsilon
C->c|epsilon
D->a|b|d
```

After applying left recursion and left factoring to it, I get the grammar as below:

```
S->A
A->BCA'|epsilon
A'->D | epsilon
B->B'
B'->bB'|epsilon
C->c|epsilon
D->a|b|d
```

But the grammar is still ambiguous. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can derive epsilon in two different ways with your second grammar.

Comment: Your first grammar accepts "abc", but your second grammar doesn't.

Comment: I don't know what LL(1) is, but as a regex your first grammar reduces to `[ad]?b*c?`, which corresponds to `S->DBC; D->a|d|epsilon; B->bB|epsilon; C->c|epsilon`.

Comment: the original grammar is ambiguous. You have to fix that first.